# Como posso executar Javascript (mais atual possível) em C#?

Tags: c#, javascript

Primeiro tentei rodar com um [controle `WebBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx)

```
WebBrowser webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();
webBrowser1.Visible = false;
webBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank");
webBrowser1.Document.Write("<html><head></head><body></body></html>");

HtmlElement head = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
dynamic scriptEl = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");

scriptEl.DomElement.text = "function test(fn) { try{ window[fn](); } catch(ex) { return 'abc     '.trim(); } }"
    + "function sayHello() { alert('ha'); throw 'erro      '; }";
head.AppendChild(scriptEl);

var result = webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("test", new object[] { "sayHello" });
```

Funciona quase perfeitamente, ele entende os objetos `window`, `alert`, mas o problema é que parece que roda em ECMA3, quando testei `"abc   ".trim()` falhou.

Minha segunda tentativa foi [Javascript .NET](https://github.com/JavascriptNet/Javascript.Net).

```
using (JavascriptContext context = new JavascriptContext())
{

    // Setando parametros externos para o contexto
    // context.SetParameter("console", new SystemConsole());
    context.SetParameter("message", "Hello World !           ");

    // Script
    string script = @"
        alert(message.trim());
    ";

    // Rodando o script
    context.Run(script);
}
```

O problema é que ele não conhece o `alert`, `window`, `document`, `console`, o único modo de reconhecer é se eu implementar tudo.

Preciso testar o Javascript para ver se está tudo rodando normalmente, para ver se não há erros e ver se não é lançado exceções.

O que mais existe? Como posso rodar Javascript com C#?

Comment: Já tentou ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb350750(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @RodrigoReis isso roda js no lado do cliente, quero rodar no lado do servidor.

Comment: @BrunoLM Você quer acessar objetos como `alert`, `window` e `document` *no servidor*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível rodar Javascript com o [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). Para isto é necessário invocá-lo utilizando `Process`.

```
try
{
    Process p = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("phantomjs.exe", "arquivo.js");

    // esconde a janela
    psi.UseShellExecute = false;
    psi.CreateNoWindow = true;

    // redireciona a saída do programa para cá
    psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

    // inicia o processo
    p.StartInfo = psi;
    p.Start();

    // obtém a saída do programa
    var output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

    p.WaitForExit();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // caso seu arquivo.js lance alguma exceção
}
```

Existe uma extensão para o Visual Studio que utiliza este método para fazer testes de unidades com TypeScript. [TSTestAdapter](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/34b2cc77-971a-4226-8f93-54518a7917ae) com [código fonte no Github](https://github.com/brunolm/TSTestExtension). O mesmo pode ser feito para Javascript puro.